# How to overload the << operator?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operator-keyword, cout

I am trying to build my own `std::vector` class but I am having trouble overloading the subscript (`[]`) and the cout `<<` operators.

So far, I have tried to define the `<<` operator as a public member of the class and then write the function's body outside the class declaration.

Right now I am getting terminal pages full of errors from `iostream` library and I do not even know where to begin looking through them.

I am a beginner in C++ and not accustomed to `friend` keyword or the `template` keyword. What am I doing wrong?

```
template<typename T>
class MyVector {
    private:
        T* Array;
    public:
        T& operator[](int b)
        {
            ...
        }

        std::ostream& output(std::ostream& s) const;
};


std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, MyVector& A)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < A.GetDimension(); i++)
    {
        output << A[i] << " ";
    }
    output << "\n";
    return output;
};
```

Comment: You cannot mix `realloc` and `new`

Comment: Because my comment is correct. If you pass a pointer from `new` to `realloc`, the result is undefined. It may work on your compiler, but blow up on another compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is right, you just forgot the template declaration:

```
template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, MyVector<T>& A)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < A.GetDimension(); i++)
    {
        output << A[i] << " ";
    }
    output << "\n";
    return output;
};
```

Comment: it probably should be.  I was just answering his question, and didn't take that close of a look at his code.

There are many other things that could be improved upon, but I thought that was out of the scope of the question and I have to leave in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

```
template<typename T>
class MyVector{
    ...
    std::ostream& printToStream(std::ostream& output) const {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < Dimension; i++) {
            output << Array[i] << " ";
        }
        output << "\n";
        return output;
    }
    ...
};

template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const MyVector<T>& A) {
   return A.printToStream(output);
}
```